# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory - error in table joining

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Here is my jpaContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect">
            </entry>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"></entry>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory"
            ref="entityManagerFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver">
        </property>
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://123.123.123.123:1433;databaseName=WikiGenome">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="xxx"></property>
        <property name="password" value="xxx"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my Disease.java:

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name="Disease")
> public class Disease {
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue
>   @Column(name="DiseaseID")
>   public int DiseaseID;
>
>   @Column(name="Name")
>   public String Name;
> }
> ```

Here is my another class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ChrPosDisease")
public class ChrPosDisease implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="chr")
    public String chr;

    @Id
    @Column(name="pos")
    public int pos;

    @Id
    @Column(name="DiseaseID")
    public int diseaseID;
}
```

I am new to hibernate and spring mvc framework and I just follows the guide in the tutorials.
I can query the result by using:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public List getDiseaseByName(String name) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("Select d From Disease d Where d.Name=?1").setParameter(1,name);
        List diseaseList=query.getResultList();
        return diseaseList;
    }
```

However, when I join two table by DiseaseID, it gives following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [Select d From cuhk.cse.fyp.model.Disease d JOIN ChrPosDisease c Where d.DiseaseID=c.DiseaseID AND d.Name=?1]
```

I don't got the error when querying the result with one table only.

Here is the code that I used to join that two table:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public List getJoinDiseaseByName(String name) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("Select d From Disease d JOIN ChrPosDisease c Where d.DiseaseID=c.DiseaseID AND d.Name=?1").setParameter(1,name);
        List diseaseList=query.getResultList();
        return diseaseList;
    }
```

What's wrong?

Thanks for help.

**Supplementary:**
Updated ChrPosDisease

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="ChrPosDisease")
public class ChrPosDisease implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="chr")
    public String chr;

    @Id
    @Column(name="pos")
    public int pos;

    @Column(name="DiseaseID")
    public int diseaseID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="DiseaseID",nullable=false)
    private Disease disease;
}
```

Updated Disease:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="Disease")
public class Disease implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="DiseaseID")
    public int DiseaseID;

    @Column(name="Name")
    public String Name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ChrPosDisease")
    private Set<ChrPosDisease> chrPosDisease = new HashSet<ChrPosDisease>();
}
```

I used above entity and there is exception in deploying.

Do I need to add anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use d.ChrPosDisease instead use just ChrPosDisease as d is an alias for only Disease entity.

and it should work.

let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Which one do you mean? 1. Select d From Disease d JOIN ChrPosDisease c Where d.DiseaseID=c.DiseaseID AND d.Name=?1  2. Select d From Disease d JOIN ChrPosDisease d Where d.Name=?1

Comment: Query query = em.createQuery("Select d From Disease d JOIN d.ChrPosDisease c Where d.DiseaseID=c.DiseaseID AND d.Name=?1").setParameter(1,name);

Comment: in the above line just see u have d.ChrPosDisease , so ChrPosDisease  is a table how can u use alias for table? remove it and try and let me know

Comment: I just following the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnbtg/index.html). Please search "Navigating to Single-Valued Relationship Fields". I am also confused with such kinds of syntax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I find that the exception is caused because I don't have "@Id" in ChrPosDisease.class. After adding the "@Id", there is a syntax error exception.  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [Select d From cuhk.cse.fyp.model.Disease d JOIN ChrPosDisease c Where d.DiseaseID=c.DiseaseID AND d.Name=?1]

Comment: Hey i cant see any mapping you have done between 2 entities. both are not related entities. try to join those entities before firing any query of join.

Comment: I updated my class above, is it correct way to map two entity?

Comment: I dont know the need of those entities so many to one or one to many i am assuming it is  needed by you.                                         but in the second entity use mappedBy ="disease".

Answer (score 0):

You should have mapping entry as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "disease")
private Set<ChrPosDisease> chrPosDisease = new HashSet<ChrPosDisease>();
```

`mappedBy` attribute notifies that the field is mapped by that particular entity property. So, this property should be the one on which connects entity on `ManyToOne` side.

Here `Disease` has many `ChrPosDisease`. And `ChrPosDisease` has one `Disease`. So mapped by column should be the one by which `OneToMany` field is bound with property on `ManyToOne` side.